# SSH connection from docker container to host

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, ssh-keys

I'm setting up rundeck inside a docker container to schedule some tasks. Rundeck by itself works. I got another problem.

I want to run bash scripts on different nodes via ssh. And I experience some strange behavior. I can ssh into a RasPi node on my network but I cannot ssh into the docker host (= my local workstation). For my docker host (named pegasus) Rundeck quits with `Failed: ConnectionFailure: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

Attempting to connect from the containers command line does not work either.

```sh
cain@pegasus:~$ docker exec -it rundeck bash

rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ ssh cain@pegasus
ssh: connect to host pegasus port 22: Connection refused
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ 
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ 
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ 
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ exit

cain@pegasus:~$ netstat -antpe
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7101            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          50331      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7440            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          52084      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        17167      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7990            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          50267      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18452      -                   
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:37626          ESTABLISHED 0          83218      -                   
tcp        0     44 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:37524          ESTABLISHED 0          82959      -                   
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:37632          ESTABLISHED 0          83338      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7101                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          51223      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9100                 :::*                    LISTEN      65534      51353      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7440                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          52089      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7990                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          50274      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18454      -
```

I'm stuck. I don't get why I can ssh into my RasPi node but not to the docker host. Seems like the name resolution for "pegasus" works because the connection is refused. Otherwise I would get a "Temporary failure in name resolution".

Connecting to my RasPi nodes even works with certs (= without password prompt). I mounted my .ssh folder into the container and mounted the hosts ssh agent.

```yaml
---
version: "3.3"
services:

  # Schedule tasks and jobs
  rundeck:
    image: pegasus/rundeck:latest
    container_name: rundeck
    command: -Dserver.http.port=7440
    tty: true
    environment:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    volumes:
      - rundeck_data:/home/rundeck/server/data
      - ./assets/rundeck/inventory.yml:/home/rundeck/inventory.yml
      - /home/cain/.ssh:/home/rundeck/.ssh:ro
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    ports:
      - 7440:7440

volumes:
  rundeck_data:
```

This confuses me even more because I would expect every ssh to work or every ssh to fail.

Even ssh-ing from my docker host to itself directly does not work ... so maybe it is more of an ssh issue than a docker issue?

```sh
cain@pegasus:~$ ssh cain@pegasus
cain@pegasus: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: I ran ssh -vvv both from my host connection to itself (first block) and from the docker container connection to the host (second block)

From docker host to docker host (= pegasus to pegasus)

```sh
cain@pegasus:~$ ssh -vvv cain@pegasus
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/cain/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "pegasus" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to pegasus [127.0.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cain/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to pegasus:22 as 'cain'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts:42
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from pegasus
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:RjctDNdVsXmLH0T8iVjtFslZjI35qtgtAgfRuO9ght0
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts:42
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from pegasus
debug1: Host 'pegasus' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/cain/.ssh/known_hosts:42
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:IRomV1oiORhfHgkIeQWkQ7fMMmi1/Y5aCJtQNLvnQaU agent
debug1: Will attempt key: sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:S+wPZoykW5eiw85Rjl/Ytt1octxNc04tRnNcE9gSPhg agent
debug1: Will attempt key: sebastian@kobol RSA SHA256:2txiA0oo1GQT7Ej9eh3iZG0P2I7JGF2EG8yq/i0kM6Y agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Q6OOlhYZCnpcIrONESO6/w8einQI1dfCsinC2cPrPSc
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:IRomV1oiORhfHgkIeQWkQ7fMMmi1/Y5aCJtQNLvnQaU agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com ED25519 SHA256:S+wPZoykW5eiw85Rjl/Ytt1octxNc04tRnNcE9gSPhg agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: sebastian@kobol RSA SHA256:2txiA0oo1GQT7Ej9eh3iZG0P2I7JGF2EG8yq/i0kM6Y agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:Q6OOlhYZCnpcIrONESO6/w8einQI1dfCsinC2cPrPSc
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/cain/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/cain/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
cain@pegasus: Permission denied (publickey).
cain@pegasus:~$ 


cain@pegasus:~/.ssh$ ll
total 72K
drwx------ 2 cain cain 4.0K Mar 10 22:48 ./
drwxr-x--- 6 cain cain 4.0K Mar 10 22:48 ../
-rw------- 1 cain cain  389 Mar 10 20:53 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 cain cain  138 Mar 10 20:55 config
-rw------- 1 cain cain  432 Mar 10 20:55 github.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 cain cain  112 Mar 10 20:55 github.key.pub
-rw------- 1 cain cain  432 Mar 10 20:55 gitlab.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 cain cain  112 Mar 10 20:55 gitlab.key.pub
-rw------- 1 cain cain 3.2K Mar 10 20:56 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 cain cain  749 Mar 10 20:56 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 cain cain 9.9K Mar 10 22:37 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 cain cain 8.6K Mar 10 20:55 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 cain cain 2.6K Mar 10 20:55 raspi-prometheus.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 cain cain  569 Mar 10 20:55 raspi-prometheus.key.pub
cain@pegasus:~/.ssh$
```

From container to docker host (= container to pegasus)

```sh
cain@pegasus:~/.ssh$ docker exec -it rundeck bash
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~$ cd .ssh/
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ ll
total 76
drwx------ 2 rundeck 1000  4096 Mar 10 21:48 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 rundeck root  4096 Mar 10 21:33 ../
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000   389 Mar 10 19:53 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 rundeck 1000   138 Mar 10 19:55 config
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000   432 Mar 10 19:55 github.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 rundeck 1000   112 Mar 10 19:55 github.key.pub
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000   432 Mar 10 19:55 gitlab.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 rundeck 1000   112 Mar 10 19:55 gitlab.key.pub
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000  3243 Mar 10 19:56 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 rundeck 1000   749 Mar 10 19:56 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000 10097 Mar 10 21:37 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000  8765 Mar 10 19:55 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 rundeck 1000  2602 Mar 10 19:55 raspi-prometheus.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 rundeck 1000   569 Mar 10 19:55 raspi-prometheus.key.pub
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ 
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ 
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv cain@pegasus
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/rundeck/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "pegasus" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to pegasus [127.0.1.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host pegasus port 22: Connection refused
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ ^C
rundeck@3223a7a31828:~/.ssh$ exit
cain@pegasus:~/.ssh$
```

Comment: Can you execute 'ssh -vvv ...' for more details?

Comment: I just did ... I updated my question with the information from `ssh -vvv ...`

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu Got any ideas? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm curious if you ever solved this? You could try host.docker.internal